# Node.js/Mongoose/lodash - server response: User Validation Failed: path `foo` is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, lodash

The error message being received is:

> "User validation failed: email: Path `email` is required., display_name: Path `display_name` is required."

The error name being sent back is: ValidationError.

The code for the ajax call is:

```
function submit_new_user(display_name, email, password){
let user_data = new New_User(display_name, email, password);
console.log(user_data);
$.ajax ({
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: user_data,
    method:'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/user',
    success: (res)=>{
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)=>{
        console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
    }
});
```

};

the console.log seen above prints:

```
New_User {display_name: "test", email: "test@test.com", password: "Passw0rd"}
```

The server route is:

```
app.post('/user', (req, res)=>{
    let body = _.pick(req.body, ['display_name', 'email', 'password']);
    let user = new User(body);
    user.save().then(()=>{
         return user.generateAuthToken();
    }).then((token)=>{
         res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    }).catch((err)=>{
         res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

This route works when pinged with Postman. The server supports cors.

The model is as follows:

```
 var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     display_name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: (val)=>{
                 return /^[\w\s]+$/.test(val);
            },
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid display name. Only 
  alphanumeric, upper and lower case characters are allowed.'
        }
     },
     email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email.'            
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        minlength: 6
    },
    tokens: [{
        access:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
});
```

I'm still learning node.js. I was guided through the creation of the API, and am trying to build a front end on my own.

The object leaving contains the three value pairs - but the object arriving, before the server changes it, is empty. I'm at loss as to why.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**: the problem was in the server-side bodyParser. I had forgotten to include the encoded url method. It was not parsing the JSON as it came in, since previously the API had only been tested using Postman there was no need to use the .urlencoded() method.